# R - Creating a random combination for elemens of two vector

Tags: r, vector, random, combinations

```
a <- rnorm(10)

b <- sample(a,18,replace = T)
```

For each element of `a`,  I want to randomly assign a value from vector `b`. So that I will have a combination for all elements of vector "a". It will be something like:

```
combinations <- data.table(first=a ,second=sample(b,length(a)))
```

What I actually want is a little different than the data.table `combinations`. I want to get a set of combinations where non of the rows has repeated values.

Edit: combinations$first[i] and combinations$second[i] may be equal in the code above. What ı want is to make it impossible to have a case where combinations$first[i] and combinations$second[i]  are equal.

Note: I will do this for large vector, so it needs to be fast.

Comment: I can't figure out what is wrong with `combinations`. Each row is already unique since `a` (`combinations$first`) has non unique values

Comment: I am a little confused. Is `b` itself not just a random sample of `a`? If you do not want repeats from `a`, then maybe you simply want `replace = F`. It is not 100% clear to me what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample by group as follows

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
a <- LETTERS[1L:10L]
output <- data.table(first=a)[, .(second=sample(setdiff(a, first), .N)), by=.(first)]
```

If random row ordering is needed, you can run `output[sample(.N)]`.

output:

```
    first second
 1:     A      J
 2:     B      D
 3:     C      E
 4:     D      G
 5:     E      J
 6:     F      B
 7:     G      J
 8:     H      J
 9:     I      F
10:     J      F
```